# Enneper's surface: differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $c \neq 0$ denote a real number.  A surface patch is given as follows:
$$ \alpha_c(u,v) = \left( \frac{u}{c^2} - \frac{u^3}{3} + uv^2,\frac{v}{c^2} - \frac{v^3}{3} + vu^2,\frac{u^2-v^2}{c} \right)$$
where $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Let  $\gamma_c(t) = \alpha_c(\cos(t), \sin(t))$, where $t \in [-\pi,\pi ]$.  Show that $\gamma_{\infty}(t) = \displaystyle \lim_{c\rightarrow \infty}\gamma_c(t)$ is a unit speed parameterized (triply covered) circle in the $(x,y)$-plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What are formulas for $\cos 3t$ and $\sin 3t$?

Comment: Thank you! that was very helpful.